# Prioritizing the most important value in an array

Tags: php

I have an array of names where I need to find the most important person.

This is my array. I cannot edit this array unless I create a copy of it

```
$data = [
    'Jack',
    'Josh',
    'Boris',
    'Bob',
    'Boris',
    'Jack',
    'Josh'
];
```

The most important person is number 1. After number 1 the most improtant person is number 2 and so on. These are the priorities.

1. Jack
2. Bob
3. Boris
4. Josh

The best way of tackling this issue I could think of is like the following:

```
$i = 5;
foreach ($data as $val) {
    if ($val == 'Jack' && $i > 1) {
        $myValue = $val;
        $i = 1;
        break;
    } else if ($val == 'Bob' && $i > 2) {
        $myValue = $val;
        $i = 2;
    } else if ($val == 'Boris' && $i > 3) {
        $myValue = $val;
        $i = 3;
    } else if ($val == 'Josh' && $i > 4) {
        $myValue = $val;
        $i = 4;
    }
}
```

It works great. But it just doesn't feel right.

Is prioritizing it like this common practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most circumstances it is better to do sorting in your SQL layer

```
<?php
$sorted_data = $data;
$importance = array_flip(['Jack', 'Bob', 'Boris', 'Josh']);
usort($sorted_data, function ($a, $b) use ($importance) {
  return $importance[$a] <=> $importance[$b];
});
$important_person = reset($sorted_data);
```

If you need to reuse your code then I suggest:

```
<?php
function sort_users(array $importance) : Closure {
  return function (string $user_a, string $user_b) use ($importance) : int {
      $a_priority = $importance[$user_a] ?? 0;
      $b_priority = $importance[$user_b] ?? 0;
      return $a_priority <=> $b_priority;
  };
}

$sorted_data = $data;
$importance = array_flip(['Jack', 'Bob', 'Boris', 'Josh']);
usort($sorted_data, sort_users($importance));
$important_person = reset($sorted_data);
```

Some of the above code can be removed if you can sort the original array, and if `$data` always contains elements of `$importance`

I would suggest thinking of a better variable name for `$data` because it's not obvious what data is, is `$first_names` better?

Comment: This nicely shows the powers of PHP 7

Comment: @Efekan I am not jealous, but my solution is more efficient, returning the result after just one iteration for your sample data. While this solution involves the sorting of the whole array :) For the reasonable array size it doesn't matter at all though

Comment: @YourCommonSense I agree, however I find that this answer has given me a more elaborate review of my code and a good way of tackling it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$importance = ['Jack','Bob', 'Boris', 'Josh'];

$rank = count($importance);
foreach ($data as $name)
{
    $rank = min($rank, array_search($name,$importance));
    if ($rank == 0) break;
}
$person = $importance[$rank];
```

Why this solution is better: you don't have to add any code in case a new person being added. You just have to add a new entry in the $importance array.

Comment: This removed that off feeling I had :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many conditions to maintain and it is not dynamic. Meaning if the importance change you have to hard code what ever you are dealing with in code. Maybe you can just add an index to your array, and store the importance next to the name, and just sort the array by your importance index.

```
$data = array(
    array('Jack',1),
    array('Josh',7),
    array('Boris',6),
    array('Bob',2),
    array('Boris',3),
    array('Jack',5),
    array('Josh'4)
);
```

If the importance change, you can just update the data in the array and sort it again.

Comment: I cannot edit the `$data` array so what I could do is create a copy of the array and set keys on it. But wouldn't I need to execute more functions doing this? I need to loop it like now, except instead of immediately setting the value I set the keys for each value and then I  sort it. Not sure which one is better.

Comment: If you give me more of your code, I can better help you come up with the best way. It is a little unclear how you are using this array.